# how to change datatype from integer to character in psql?

Tags: psql

ı need to change the datatype of a column .

ALTER TABLE students
ALTER COLUMN "Dname" character varying (30) ;

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this statement instead.

ALTER TABLE students
  MODIFY Dname varchar2(30);

Best,

Yassine